# Construir menu circular em css

Tags: javascript, css, menu

Alguém sabe me dar alguma dica de como construir um menu simples, como o desse gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKWr5.gif
Ou parecido.
Para uma página web, já tentei de algumas maneiras, mas falta conhecimento.

Comment: Você poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código que tentou fazer? Assim não ficará parecendo que você quer que façamos o código para você de graça.

Comment: Olá Deivid Santos, seja bem-vindo! comece a se inteirar de certas regras para um melhor aproveitamento desse site visitando https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485 E TAMBÉM https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você pode fazer da seguinte forma. O segredo é conseguir lidar com os `transform: rotate` e os `position`

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  box-sizing: content-box;  
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: url('https://ak6.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/5790803/thumb/1.jpg?i10c=img.resize(height:160)');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
  background-size: cover;
}

.esfera {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;  
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid silver;  
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.menus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 50%;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu .background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}


.menu:hover .background {
  background-color: black;
}

.centro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 4px solid silver;  
  background: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/shiny-diamond-polygonal-background_23-2147614103.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="esfera">
    <div class="menus">
      <div id="menu1" class="menu">      
        <div class="background"></div>   
        <span>Products</span>
      </div>
      <div id="menu3" class="menu">      
        <div class="background"></div>  
        <span>Gallery</span>
      </div>
      <div id="menu2" class="menu">      
        <div class="background"></div>   
        <span>News</span>
      </div>
      <div id="menu4" class="menu">      
        <div class="background"></div>   
        <span>Downloads</span>
      </div>
      <div class="centro">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito legal esse tipo de menu, o problema é quanto a responsividade, aí tem que trabalhar um pouco mais no codigo pra funcionar em telas menores.

Answer (score 4):

Fiz este exemplo abaixo me baseando [neste código](https://codepen.io/StvGo/pen/wAoDK). Acredito estar bem próximo do que precisa. O que vai ter que mudar é o menu 5 para ter uma imagem de background e não cor.

```css
ul.menu {
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

ul.menu li {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.menu li:nth-child(5):hover {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  top: 0em;
  left: 0em;
  line-height: 8em;
  background: #90f;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 19;
}

ul.menu li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #90d;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
}

ul.menu li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0em;
  left: 10em;
  background: #7f00b7;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
}

ul.menu li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 10em;
  left: 0;
  background: #57007d;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%
}

ul.menu li:nth-child(4) {
  top: 10em;
  left: 10em;
  background: #6a0098;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%
}

ul.menu li:nth-child(5) {
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  top: 6em;
  left: 6em;
  line-height: 8em;
  background: #90f;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
}

ul.menu li div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.menu li div span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <div><span>MENU1</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><span>MENU2</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><span>MENU3</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><span>MENU4</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><span>MENU5</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma das maneiras é usando pontos de acesso e mapas de imagem.

> Um ponto de acesso pode ser uma forma ou um texto em um elemento gráfico que seja também um hiperlink. Quando um visitante do site clica na forma ou no texto, o destino do hiperlink é exibido em um navegador da Web. Os pontos de acesso podem ter a forma de retângulos, círculos ou polígonos.

Um elemento gráfico com um ou mais pontos de acesso chama-se. [**mapa de imagem**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp). Image map (mapa da imagem) é uma extensão que permite que diferentes áreas de uma imagem sejam clicáveis. É uma lista de coordenadas associadas a uma imagem que associa a determinadas áreas da imagem links para vários destinos.   [Image map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)

### **1 - Imagens responsivas**   [jQuery-rwdImageMaps](http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html)

### **2 - Imagens não responsivas**

**2.1** Exemplo com links [**DEMO**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/menu-circular.htm)

```
<map name="FPMap0">
    <area target="_blank" href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest" shape="polygon" coords="114, 64, 133, 50, 153, 43, 178, 32, 205, 29, 228, 32, 255, 44, 275, 57, 288, 64, 239, 112, 227, 103, 204, 97, 189, 100, 173, 106, 166, 114" alt="Perguntas não respondidas">
    <area target="_blank" href="https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485" shape="polygon" coords="286, 239, 236, 189, 249, 173, 253, 154, 252, 137, 247, 122, 241, 113, 289, 63, 305, 85, 313, 103, 319, 127, 322, 148, 320, 174, 315, 199, 304, 215">
    <area target="_blank" href="https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079" shape="polygon" coords="164, 189, 115, 237, 132, 250, 149, 261, 173, 270, 200, 272, 227, 271, 245, 264, 266, 254, 286, 241, 238, 191, 219, 201, 198, 205, 183, 202, 172, 194, 167, 188, 165, 185">
    <area target="_blank" href="http://www.globo.com/" shape="polygon" coords="164, 187, 152, 171, 148, 148, 156, 126, 165, 112, 114, 65, 100, 81, 92, 99, 84, 114, 80, 138, 82, 168, 90, 196, 102, 216, 111, 229, 116, 238">
    </map>
    <img border="0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvpVD.png" width="400" height="300" usemap="#FPMap0">
```

**2.2** - Neste exemplo as áreas clicáveis são os olhos

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHSnU.jpg" usemap="#Map" id='imagem' class="fixed-background" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
 <area href="#" onClick="alert('Olho esquerdo');" shape="poly" coords="339,207,311,221,319,247,352,258,374,247,380,214,362,207" />
 <area href="#" onClick="alert('Olho direito');"  shape="poly" coords="369,305,327,320,325,350,338,382,357,383,384,369,395,343,389,314" />
</map>
```

[image: Map support]

**Muito bem Sr. Leo Caracciolo**, mas como é que eu vou saber colocar esses números todos ai para delimitar a área que eu quero para cada link?

- Fácil, use essa ferramenta on-line    [Easy Imagemap Generator](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/)